# Yarn can't build local package correctly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I'm building my own package and I have an example folder in my project as well. My project structure is like this:

```
 - node_modules
 - example
    -node_modeules
           - my-library
    -index.html
    -index.js
    -package.json 
- src
   -library.jsx
package.json
```

Inside **example** folder, the `package.json` file has:

```
"dependencies":{
    "my-library":"file:../"
}
```

and when I run  `npm install`, I can see my library is built up correctly and then added to `example\node_modules\` . Everything is just as expected.

However, when I tried the same thing with `yarn install`, it didn't work -- note I have **cleared the Yarn cache**, so it's not a cache issue. The problem is that, when running `yarn install`, it seems Yarn doesn't honour my package.json in root folder, i.e.

inside **root folder** , the `package.json` file contains

```
"name":"my-library"
"version":"1.0.0"
"main":"lib/result.js"
"files":"["lib"]"
```

which tells npm to only include `lib` folder in the result package -- npm is following the instruction well, but seems Yarn has completely ignored it and put **everything** in the result package.

Note: if I publish my library to the npm registry, and then do `yarn install my-library` everything works as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I encourage everyone have a try.

```
-root
    - example
        -package.json
    -lib
      -lib.js
    -src
      -test.js
    package.json
```

in **root\package.json**, try

```
"main":"lib\lib.js"
"files":["lib"]
```

then in **root\example\package.json**, have

```
dependencies:{
   "parent":"file:../"
}
```

to test the difference

1. `cd root\example\;    npm install`
2. `cd root\example\;    yarn install`

compare the result in `root\example\node_modues\parent\`

the npm one only has `lib` folder, but the yarn one has **everything** (both lib and src )

why is such a case?

Comment: yarn seems to handle `files` wrong. I published something on npm with yarn yesterday, the resulting archive was just empty. Publishing with npm, it had the listed files and readme, package.json, etc...

Comment: Note there's an open issue for this specific one, and your issue is probably related

Comment: I created one issue there